# Angular firestore array_contains on objects

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following document:

```
{
    "ID" : "01",
    "Name" : "A1",
    "players" : [ {
        "active" : false,
        "name" : "dissident"
      }, {
        "active" : false,
        "name" : "ink"
      }
    ]
}
```

Wrote it down in JSON so it's easier to understand.
Now what I want to do with firestore is query on the players[*].name.
I have seen the new option to use "array_contains".

But I have seen all examples use an array of string instead of an array of objects.
Is it possible to query over the players[*].name?

This is what I tried:

```
this.afs.collection('Locations', ref => ref.where('players.name', 'array-contains', _name))
```

Based on @camden_kid reaction I build:

```
this.locationsCollection = this.afs.collection('Locations', ref => ref.where('players', 'array-contains', {active : false, name : _name}) );
if(this.locationsCollection === undefined){
    this.locationsCollection = this.afs.collection('Locations', ref => ref.where('players', 'array-contains', {active : true, name : _name}) );
}
```

But this is depended on the active value to, this will not work on every kind of situation.

Comment: Have you tried testing against the whole object? E.g. `this.afs.collection('Locations', ref => ref.where('players', 'array-contains', {active : false, name : _name}))`

Comment: You can add this as an answer this is working :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try testing against the whole object, e.g.

```
this.afs.collection('Locations', ref => ref.where('players', 'array-contains', {active : false, name : _name}))
```

Comment: Like I explained in my question this is a good workaround but it will require also to check if active is true. If there are more object items this will not work.

Comment: @Swoox That is true and it is only possible to do one 'array-contains' test otherwise it throws an error. Let me have a think.

Comment: @Swoox Would spitting your data into two arrays of names help in any way? E.g. `players_active`, `players_inactive`.

Comment: This will make it quite complex and every number have to match eachother.

Comment: In the end I followed you solution I added location to the players and moved them to a different collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this on objects in the way where you are looking for one parameter.  Firestore doesnʻt support this (annoyingly).  I looked at several ways of doing this.  John Delaney's Firestore Modeling course looks to address these issues and more.

A better way would be to have two arrays one containing just the id/guids as strings and use array-contains on that.

If you still need the objects just create/have the second array with the objects and when you add objects to one, you add the string to another.