# how to set data to firebase map object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, firebase

I have a firebase map object and i need to insert arrays inside

I am trying to use update function but it doesn't work

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);

  const arrayname = result.name;
  const fireupdate = this.af.list('/users/' + this.Uid + '/items').update(arrayname, result);
});
```

this is how the result array looks like

```
{name: "item", price: 25, desc: "a simple item"}
```

I don't get anything in the firebase
[image: here is my firebase structure]

Comment: Is it just an array or an array of objects?

Comment: array of objects @Swoox

Comment: `{name: "item", price: 25, desc: "a simple item"}` this array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what is easiest to do is add the array to the doc as shown in the other answer.

```
this.db.collection("users").doc(this.Uid).update({items: [{name: "item", price: 25, desc: "a simple item"}, {name: "item2", price: 20, desc: "a simple item2"}]})
```

What you must be careful about is that firestore not really have a good way to query an array with objects yet:

[query an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52053200/angular-firestore-array-contains-on-objects)

What Firestore want you to do is basicly:

```
this.db.collection("users").doc(this.Uid).collection('items').add({name: "item", price: 25, desc: "a simple item"})
```

Comment: if I add this can I add another array later ?? @Swoox

Comment: the problem is that I am adding thid kind of array not just once

Comment: Yeah I was looking for something like this myself awell

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: Seems not they only support array like ['north', 'south']. I edited my answer with the way the want it.

Comment: ya it's complicated but works. if I save the data this way how can i retrieve it ..say I have a user collection then I have uid then another collection item and then another id and the arrays I want every array in a separate id can I loop throw all o them and get the arrays? @Swoox

Comment: Yah you can do `this.db.collection("users").doc(this.Uid).collection('items').valueChanges().subscribe()` there should be enough information about this on google.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaking, by doing `this.af.list('/users/' + this.Uid + '/items').update()` you are actually trying to write to the [**Realtime Database**](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database), see https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#updating-items-in-the-list-using-update

But the database that you show in your question is [**Firestore**](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore), the other database service offered by Firebase.

You should use the part of the angularfire2 library dedicated to Firestore, see https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#using-angularfirestoredocument

Comment: i changed it to            item[result.name]=result;
     this.db.collection("users").doc(this.Uid).update({items:item}) but the data is overwritten every time do you have any idea why?

Comment: It does overwrite every time.
if you want to update only the price you can do `{ price: 1 }` and not all the other properties.

Comment: no, I simply want to add more arrays ... I want to add to the items more arrays with these fields   @Swoox